# What is the command line that Visual Studio uses to install SQL Express?

Tags: installation, automation, sql-server-2008

I'm writing an application that will download and install all the prerequisites for a larger application.  One of those prerequisites is SQL Express 2008.  I need my application to be able to install SQL entirely unattended, without any interaction from the user.

The problem with this is that the documentation I've found states that user accounts and their passwords need to be specified for each of the services that are installed.  There is no way for me to have this information at the time when SQL Express is installed.

When installing Visual Studio, SQL Express is installed exactly as I want it installed for my deployment.  What is the command line that the Visual Studio installer passes to the SQL Express installer?